# Дата в именительном падеже

Tags: java

Подскажите как сделать дату в именительном падеже?

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM yyyy");
String monthAndYear = simpleDateFormat.format(firstDate.getTime()).toUpperCase();
```

Данный код выводит АВГУСТА 2021 а НУЖНО АВГУСТ 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Замени MMMM на LLLL и учись читать документацию.